# zend framework / view <?= does not work ? why?

Tags: php, php-ini, php-shorttags

Strange.. with my installation of the Zend Framework

```
<?php echo $this->user; ?>   works fine but
<?= $this->user; ?> does not work
```

Anyone have an idea what is the problem ?

Comment: You don't need the ;. The ?> adds a closing ; to the code

Comment: nice.. wow this looks much cleaner, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your php.ini, you probably have short tags disabled. See [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your server configuration has short_open_tag turned off. This is generally a good thing, short_open_tag saves you some characters but can cause problems while parsing some types of documents.

I'd leave it off unless you know for sure that you will need it.

Answer (score 0):

`short_open_tag` is not enabled.